# Nao inverse kinematics

Tags: robotic-arm, kinematics, ik, nao, inverse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

What options do I have in ROS for controlling a Nao robots body parts using inverse kinematics (e.g. its arms)?

Or would I need to write a wrapper so that ROS can use Naoqi's inverse kinematics solver?

Kind Regards

Jamie

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57200/nao-inverse-kinematics/) by [James Diprose](https://answers.ros.org/users/3239/james-diprose/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2013-03-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the NaoQI IK solver with a wrapper, but I found it often to inaccurate and it will give a close approx. solution instead of failing in some cases. It's also only possible to execute the trajectory to the IK solution afaik, not to compute/simulate it and then integrate it in some own implementation.

So you can use any kind of IK available in ROS based in the Nao's model in the nao_description package. E.g. using [IKFast](http://ros.org/wiki/Industrial/Tutorials/Create_a_Fast_IK_Solution) of OpenRAVE or the iterative IK in KDL. We used both in our implementation for the Nao: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VUmnFy58w90

KDL is more general but slower than IKFast. With IKFast and the Nao (lacking a 6DoF arm), you can only set 3D or 5D IK goals.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2013-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [James Diprose](https://answers.ros.org/users/3239/james-diprose/) on 2013-03-10**:
Cool thanks for your answer, I'll give those a go.